# How to insert serialized array in MySQL DB using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried endless variations of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to insert a simple array in a column ni one of my tables. The contents of the column is blank everytime.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this query?

```
$accessRights = array(
  'S-01' => 'Y',
  'S-02' => 'Y',
);
$accessRights = serialize( $accessRights );

mysqli_query( $GLOBALS['db_link'], 'SET NAMES "utf8"' ); // to ensure proper encoding of special characters
$query_string = '
  UPDATE users_accessRights
  SET
    accessRights = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string( $accessRights ) . '"
  WHERE userID = "' . $_POST['userID'] . '"
  LIMIT 1
';
mysqli_query( $GLOBALS['db_link'], $query_string ) or die( mysqli_error( $GLOBALS['db_link'] ) );
```

Note: I can use this query to insert a simple text string into the table, so I know the query itself works.

Comment: Why not save yourself all this trouble and use a prepared statement with bound parameters? Also, you should use [`mysqli_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.set-charset.php) instead of the `SET NAMES` query

Comment: Terrific @Phil - I like _saving myself trouble_... Now the question is what does your suggestion mean and how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you do not have sufficient error reporting enabled to have noticed a syntax error in your code. [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires **two** arguments, not one. You should make sure your development environment's `php.ini` has the following entries set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Alternatively, place this at the top of your script but remove it for *production*

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

A better way to create queries with variable / user input is [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). For example

```
// set mysqli to throw exceptions so you don't have to check return
// values for false or use "or die"
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$mysqli = $GLOBALS['db_link']; // I suggest you avoid using globals like this ASAP

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    'UPDATE users_accessRights SET accessRights = ? WHERE userID = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('si', $accessRights, $_POST['userID']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This assumes that `userID` is an integer field.

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try -- thanks @Phil...(and yes, userID is an integer -- key field)

Comment: @H.Ferrence cool, that's what the "i" in "si" is for (the "s" being for "string"). Let me know how you go and make sure you read that prepared statement quickstart guide for a deeper understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I got it to work via `mysqli_real_escape_string( $GLOBALS['db_link'], $accessRights )`. I need to look into Prepared Statements and begun to understand that method. Thanks for the help and the tip.